# Mysterious table array definition in VLOOKUP formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I've inherited an Excel spreadsheet which contains the following formula, which I'm trying to debug:

```
=VLOOKUP($G$3,AllFE,79,FALSE)
```

I understand every part of this formula except the`AllFE` (table array) element. Is this an alias for the actual row/column definition?

If so, how do I translate the alias into the actual sheet/rows/columns the formula is looking at?

I'm using Microsoft Excel for Mac 16.

Comment: AllFE is the name of a table.  [Here is a tutorial](http://www.contextures.com/xlExcelTable01.html) on creating and naming tables.  And [here is a discussion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/261178/locating-name-manager-in-excel-for-mac) about how to see and manage the names in an Excel for Mac 2016 spreadsheet and their associated ranges.

Comment: @Bandersnatch , you may post that in the answer tab for the benefit of others later. ( :